# Retrieve real-time data from firebase for specific user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Answer to this has been posted without the PostIME error here : [View PostIME 0,1 error while retrieving data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972719/view-postime-0-1-error-while-retrieving-data-from-firebase/60972830?noredirect=1#comment107873770_60972830)

Thanks to @Alex Mamo and @Peter Haddad

Thanks @Akash Starvin Dsouza for trying.

My database :

[image]

I have given an ID to every user. And I want to retrieve the data of the specific user who is currently logged into the app.
I am using this code wherein I am explicitly specifying the node under user details. What are the changes to be done?

```
showb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Details").child("1");
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String namep=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String heightp=dataSnapshot.child("height").getValue().toString();
                        String weightp=dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue().toString();
                        String genderp=dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                        String emailp=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        name.setText(namep);
                        height.setText(heightp);
                        weight.setText(weightp);
                        gender.setText(genderp);
                        mail.setText(emailp);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Code used for SAVING data - email id, gender, height, name, weight:

```
msave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        msave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //n
                String uName= uname.getText().toString().trim();
                Float uHeight = Float.parseFloat(uheight.getText().toString().trim());
                Float uWeight = Float.parseFloat(uweight.getText().toString().trim());
                String uGender= ugender.getText().toString().trim();
                String uEmail=  msuser.getText().toString().trim();

                ud.setName(uName);
                ud.setHeight(uHeight);
                ud.setWeight(uWeight);
                ud.setGender(uGender);
                ud.setEmail(uEmail);
                reference.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(ud);
                //n

                final String email= msuser.getText().toString();

                String pwd=mspass.getText().toString();
                String cpwd=msconfpass.getText().toString();

                if(email.isEmpty()){
                    msuser.setError("Please enter email id");
                    msuser.requestFocus();
                }

                else if(pwd.isEmpty()){
                    mspass.setError("Please enter the password");
                    mspass.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(cpwd.isEmpty()){
                    msconfpass.setError("Please enter password again");
                    msconfpass.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty() && cpwd.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!cpwd.equals(pwd)){
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Please enter same password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty() && cpwd.isEmpty())){

                    mfirebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(Signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Signup Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully and You're now logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this,Login.class));
                                //Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me at first glance, except for the fact that you failed to implement `onCancelled`. The minimum implementation for that is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. Aside from that: what is the problem when you run this code? For example: when you run it in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Okay will remove the android studio tag. There's no error in this. Instead of explicitly mentioning the child node I want to display data of current logged in user.

Comment: How do you know what data is for the currently logged in user? I.e. what identifies the currently logged in user?

Comment: Actually nothing identifies the currently logged in user. I want the mail to be used as an identifier. How do I do that?

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to add user data to the database.

Comment: I have posted the code for saving data in the question. Please have a look at it. @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I want the mail to be used as an identifier. How do I do that?

To achieve that, you should pass the email address into the reference when writing data to Firestore. So please change the following line of code:

```
reference.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(ud);
```

To:

```
reference.child(uEmail).setValue(ud);
```

In this way, you'll not have those ascending numbers as identifiers but the email address. Another more appropriate approach would be to use as a unique identifier the `uid` that comes from the authentication process. The main reason is the user can change the email address over time while the `uid` will always be the same.

Comment: Okay I'll keep the unique identifier instead of 1,2,3 and so on. After I have done that how do I get the data for specific user?

Comment: Using the following reference: `reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Details").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());`.

Comment: Getting this error after clicking on show button : ViewPostIme pointer 0, ViewPostIme pointer 1. @Alex Mamo

Comment: Cannot understand much from that error. If you have a hard hard time implementing that, please post a new question with the complete stack trace, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I have posted a new question. Pls check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972719/view-postime-0-1-error-while-retrieving-data-from-firebase

Comment: Yes I have done that, please have a look at the new post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Details").orderByChild("email").equalTo("yyy@gmail.com");
```

Here "email" should match database key value

```
orderByChild("email")
```

You should get email id of the when the user logs in, and pass it to

```
equalTo(strEmailId)
```

Sending data

```
Intent intoHome=new Intent(Login.this,HomeActivity.class);
intoHome.putExtra("email_key", email);
startActivity(intoHome);
```

Receiving data

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
strRecivedEmail = extras.getString("email_key");
```

Comment: ```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference strEmailId=database.getReference("email" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser());
reference= (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Details").orderByChild("email").equalTo(String.valueOf(strEmailId));
``` Application crashes now.

Comment: Ok, new here. How do I post the code properly in comments?

Comment: First, get the emailId and print it in logcat, once you get current user email Id then pass it as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: How do I get the mail id? Unable to get that.

Comment: In login activity when user types email ID and clicks login, pass it to next activity using Intents

Comment: please check the above answer, for login activity

Comment: I have added how to send and receive data between activities.

Comment: whats "email_key"? the logcat thing thing you were talking about?

Comment: "email_key" is key to get that value, you can even send multiple values using different keys. These keys are user defined

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for checking up. Actually I haven't tried this one yet, had another project to work on. Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Yes I will let you know

Comment: Tried your code. It gives me null pointer exception. @Akash Starvin Dsouza