# View PostIME 0,1 error while retrieving data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I am trying to display the data for the current logged in user. If there is any other method to retrieve data pls share.

This is my database :

[image]
This is the code I have used for saving data :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        mfirebase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        msuser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        mspass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        mloginn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.already);
        msconfpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);

        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        ugender=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ugender);
        uheight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uheight);
        uweight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uweight);
        ud= new UserDetails();

        reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");

        msave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        msave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //n
                String uName= uname.getText().toString().trim();
                Float uHeight = Float.parseFloat(uheight.getText().toString().trim());
                Float uWeight = Float.parseFloat(uweight.getText().toString().trim());
                String uGender= ugender.getText().toString().trim();
                String uEmail=  msuser.getText().toString().trim();

                ud.setName(uName);
                ud.setHeight(uHeight);
                ud.setWeight(uWeight);
                ud.setGender(uGender);
                ud.setEmail(uEmail);
                reference.push().setValue(ud);
                //n

                email= msuser.getText().toString();
                String pwd=mspass.getText().toString();
                String cpwd=msconfpass.getText().toString();

                if(email.isEmpty()){
                    msuser.setError("Please enter email id");
                    msuser.requestFocus();
                }

                else if(pwd.isEmpty()){
                    mspass.setError("Please enter the password");
                    mspass.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(cpwd.isEmpty()){
                    msconfpass.setError("Please enter password again");
                    msconfpass.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty() && cpwd.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!cpwd.equals(pwd)){
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Please enter same password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty() && cpwd.isEmpty())){

                    mfirebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(Signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Signup Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully and You're now logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this,Login.class));
                                //Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the code I have used for retrieving the data :

```
showb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //reference= (DatabaseReference) FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").orderByChild("email").equalTo(strEmailId);
                reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String namep=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String heightp=dataSnapshot.child("height").getValue(String.class);
                        String weightp=dataSnapshot.child("weight").getValue(String.class);
                        String genderp=dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailp=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        name.setText(namep);
                        height.setText(heightp);
                        weight.setText(weightp);
                        gender.setText(genderp);
                        mail.setText(emailp);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the error shown after clicking on showb (Button used for displaying in text fields):
After clicking on showb the error is as follows :

```
2020-04-01 19:28:18.285 7996-7996/com.zzz.fitness D/ViewRootImpl@133c623[UserProfile]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2020-04-01 19:28:18.359 7996-7996/com.zz.fitness D/ViewRootImpl@133c623[UserProfile]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Comment: How do you verify if your user is logged-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the values under a random id:

```
 reference.push().setValue(ud);
```

This code generates a random id and under it you will have the attributes of class `UserDetails`, you need to change it to the following:

```
     mfirebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(Signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Signup Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully and You're now logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
reference.child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(ud); //add this line
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this,Login.class));
                                //Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Account Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

After you change it to the above, then when you retrieve you can use this:

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Comment: This in : [reference.child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(ud);] !task.isSuccessful (not successful) part or the else part where it creates the account successfully? Cz I tried that and it gives me the same error. @Peter Haddad

Comment: please check the edit, also dont forget to remove `reference.push().setValue(ud);`

Comment: I have removed the code from showb button and posted the code in onCreate. It works but it takes a second or 2 to load after opening the activity. What's the issue here, why not instantaneously?. Happens everytime I open the activity. Anything I can do to make it load faster?  @Peter Haddad

Comment: its asynchronous ofcourse it will take a bit of time, even more if u have bad cinnection

Comment: Okay fine, I'll add a progress bar(loading icon) so that it'll look better. Thanks again.